# Change Snap server parameters

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I have created a project using

```
snap init barebones
```

Is there a way to turn logging on/off and examine or set any server parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the module [Snap.Http.Server.Config](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server-0.9.2.4/docs/Snap-Http-Server-Config.html). You can create a specialized `Config` using the functions from there, then pass them into a call to `simpleHttpServe` from [Snap.Http.Server](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server-0.9.4.5/docs/Snap-Http-Server.html) to start a server with your custom options.